# Sinking and sourcing problem for buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, source, offset

[image]

Let's assume that I am using a buffer for a sensor output (V1) in the kHz domain. The output of the buffer will be ideally equivalent to the sensor voltage. There will ideally be no current coming out of the op amp. However, there's a current source (I1) on right side of the buffer. R1 has a high resistance, so the current might be sunk by the op amp. I assume the op amp will sink the current when the sensor voltage (V1) is negative and below ground.

Will this cause a DC offset for the AC sensor voltage? And how can I deal with this?

In real-life the current source is a current diode, but for this scenario I will simplify it to a current source. However, it will not be constant, and will vary depending on a lot of different factors.

Should I use some sort of resistor with switches to sink the varying current source that is between 4.6 mA to 5.1 mA?

Comment: The presence of C1 will make the opamp sink *all* of the 5.1mA from the source, with R1 seeing none of it. It seems to me that because of C1, the current source serves no purpose here except to cause the opamp to be permanently sinking. Is that what you intend here? Also, your opamp's positive supply pin is at -15V.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the low effort. The supply pin is of course -15 V. The current source, R1 and C1 are a part of a interface that I want to interact with. So I can not change these values. You are completely right that the capacitor will force the op amp to sink all of the current, because the capacitor is blocking for R1. 

Could it be a suggestion to use another resistor that is connected to ground, so the op amp will not sink all of the current too avoid DC offset?

Comment: If the "DC offset" you are talking about is referring to the 5.1mA of *current*, then this particular opamp will probably sink it without trouble, and without anyone even knowing it's there. If by "DC offset" you mean some *voltage* offset, at the opamp's output, then I would say that the opamp will win the fight, and be able to impose whatever voltage you ask it to, again because its output will absorb and overcome the 5.1mA.

Comment: In either case, the sensor (modelled by V1 I presume) is almost completely unloaded by the opamp input, and so is effectively isolated from the rest of the circuit. So it's not clear what you mean by "DC offset", and where you think this offset might be present.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 

I did a simulation earlier, where there was a RC filter at the output between the op amp the current source. This caused a DC offset. Now, when the RC filter is on the right side of the current source, it did not cause any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There will ideally be no current coming out of the op amp.

That's not true. There will ideally be no current into the inverting input (which is connected to the op amp output), but the op amp output will try to source or sink whatever current is necessary to keep its inputs at the same voltage (i.e. to set its output voltage equal to \$V_1\$). The caveat is that you have to make sure the op amp's output current would not need to exceed what its datasheet says is its maximum output current. [Its datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP777_727_747.pdf) says on page 3 that it can supply +/-30 mA (typical) with +/-15 V supplies (as you are using), so there should be no problem for a current source of ~5 mA.

You can calculate the op amp's output current mathematically. Let \$I_{\text{out}}\$ be the current sourced by the op amp and \$I_{L}\$ be the load current through \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$, both flowing to the right. Also let $$Z_L = \frac{1}{sC_1} + R_1$$

By KCL $$I_{\text{out}} + I_1 = I_L$$

Since the op amp is a buffer its output voltage (and the voltage across \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$)  will be $$V_1 = I_L Z_L = (I_{\text{out}} + I_1) Z_L$$

Solving for \$I_{\text{out}}\$ we have $$I_{\text{out}} = \frac{V_1}{Z_L} - I_1$$

Just make sure \$I_{\text{out}}\$ is less than +/-30 mA (or, to be safe, more like +/-20 mA) regardless of \$V_1\$ and \$I_1\$.

Answer (score 1):

Your Assumptions:

> Op Amp current output is zero:

Only if Vin=0. Otherwise False. The current will equal the Current diode source on the output. But that does not induce any  output offset voltage as the open loop output impedance of 120 Ohms and is reduced by the 300k minimum open loop gain.  But Zo rises to open loop gain towards minimum GBW.  The table indicates +/-10 mA nominal output with < 1V dropout.

> The output will sink current if the input goes negative below single supply 0V.

It is not guaranteed to operate with gain for Vin < Vss but will operate to spec within 1mV above Vss. Effects unknown for negative inputs. It may be unstable.

“ Output Stage
The CMOS output stage has excellent (and fairly symmetric) output drive and with light loads can actually swing to within 1 mV of both supply rails. This is considerably better than similar amplifiers featuring (so-called) rail-to-rail bipolar output stages. OP777/ OP727/OP747 is stable in the voltage follower configuration and responds to signals as low as 1 mV above ground in single supply operation”